# Listing ODBC Data Sources in C#

Tags: c#, odbc

I'm looking for a properly abstract way to get a list of ODBC data sources from the system in C#. I've tried the "Poking-around-in-the-registry" trick, which I've found works fine in English:

```
        RegistryKey reg = (Registry.CurrentUser).OpenSubKey("Software");
        reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC");
        reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC.INI");
        reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC Data Sources");

        and then, of course, iterating over reg.GetValueNames()
```

Only problem is that I've discovered on at least one Spanish machine that their Registry keys are, well, in Spanish, so clearly violating this abstraction (if it exists) has already gotten me into trouble.

Is there a library function to do this?

Answer (score 20):

You could call the SQLDataSources-function in ODBC32.DLL:

```
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    public static class OdbcWrapper
    {
        [DllImport("odbc32.dll")]
        public static extern int SQLDataSources(int EnvHandle, int Direction, StringBuilder ServerName, int ServerNameBufferLenIn,
    ref int ServerNameBufferLenOut, StringBuilder Driver, int DriverBufferLenIn, ref int DriverBufferLenOut);

        [DllImport("odbc32.dll")]
        public static extern int SQLAllocEnv(ref int EnvHandle);
    }
```

Example that lists the Data Sources:

```
public void ListODBCsources()
    {
        int envHandle=0;
        const int SQL_FETCH_NEXT = 1;
        const int SQL_FETCH_FIRST_SYSTEM = 32;

        if (OdbcWrapper.SQLAllocEnv(ref envHandle) != -1)
        {
            int ret;
            StringBuilder serverName = new StringBuilder(1024);
            StringBuilder driverName = new StringBuilder(1024);
            int snLen = 0;
            int driverLen = 0;
            ret = OdbcWrapper.SQLDataSources(envHandle, SQL_FETCH_FIRST_SYSTEM, serverName, serverName.Capacity, ref snLen,
                        driverName, driverName.Capacity, ref driverLen);
            while (ret == 0)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(serverName + System.Environment.NewLine + driverName);
                ret = OdbcWrapper.SQLDataSources(envHandle, SQL_FETCH_NEXT, serverName, serverName.Capacity, ref snLen,
                        driverName, driverName.Capacity, ref driverLen);
            } 
        }

    }
```

The first call to SQLDataSources with `SQL_FETCH_FIRST_SYSTEM` tells the function to start the listing with the System-DSNs. If you simply started with `SQL_FETCH_NEXT` it would first list the drivers. [Link to the function ref on Microsofts site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711004(VS.85).aspx)

Edit:
Everybody seems to know it but I just found out yesterday when I used this code in a new poject: if you are compiling this with VS on a 64 Bit Windows you have to set the "Target Platform" to "x86" or the code won't run.

Comment: Awesome answer.  I had to look up SQL_FETCH_FIRST_USER to get it to work in my environment, but that was trivial.  Cheers.

Comment: @Stephan Keller can you please help me with sqlgetinfo function in c#

Comment: @Arshad: Sorry, I never needed to use SQLGetInfo so I have no implementation for it.

Answer (score 10):

I use the following code to retrieve the DSNs from the registry :

```
    private List<string> EnumDsn()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.AddRange(EnumDsn(Registry.CurrentUser));
        list.AddRange(EnumDsn(Registry.LocalMachine));
        return list;
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> EnumDsn(RegistryKey rootKey)
    {
        RegistryKey regKey = rootKey.OpenSubKey(@"Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources");
        if (regKey != null)
        {
            foreach (string name in regKey.GetValueNames())
            {
                string value = regKey.GetValue(name, "").ToString();
                yield return name;
            }
        }
    }
```

It's strange that you have non-english name for the "ODBC Data Sources" key... I have a French version of Windows, and the name is still in English

Comment: Interesting comment about French version.  Good eye!  Can anyone else confirm this is true for other languages (Chinese, Japanese, Korean)?  Also, does this change between XP, W7, W8?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but for what it's worth at windows 10 I found the ODBC connection located in the LocalMachine node and not the current user, could be a 64bit thing.

```
        RegistryKey reg = (Registry.LocalMachine).OpenSubKey("Software");
        reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC");
        reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC.INI");
        reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC Data Sources");
        string instance = "";
        foreach (string item in reg.GetValueNames())
        {
            instance = item;
        }
```

Comment: in my x64 windows 10, I also find  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\odbc\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources
also HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\odbc\ODBC.INI\ODBC File DSN

I also found these in a x86 windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything in .NET, and a quick check of the (native) ODBC API shows some functions that might be of help:

- SQLBrowseConnec
- SQLDrivers

Given the way buffers are used in the ODBC API, careful pinning of character arrays will be needed.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a Windows Forms Application (not a Web environment), you could use the Visual Studio's "Choose Data Source" dialog.

It's included in an assembly and can be easily used.

The article where I found this info:
http://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/MZ2007011.aspx

In any case, I'm from Spain and I also use the Registry solution (specially in Web apps). I've never found a machine with those entries in a language different from English.

Comment: If a user specifically asks how to do something in code. Responding with a method to perform the same action within the IDE isn't applicable. Also, your link on mztools is broken.